# Crystal Report error when joining two Sqlite tables ;Database schema has changed near "inner": syntax error?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, join, crystal-reports

I am using Vb net ,
I get this error while pulling data from two tables of Sqlite database into Crystal Reports:
"Database schema has changed near "inner": syntax error ?" 
This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnReportPontes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReportPontes.Click

  Dim rpt As New CrystalReport3()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
    Dim myds As Data.DataSet = New Data.DataSet()
    Using cn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection With
           {
               .ConnectionString = SqliteBuilder.ConnectionString
           }
        Using cmd As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand With {.Connection = cn}

        cmd.CommandText = " SELECT LesPontes.Pontes, LesPontes.Cage,LesPontes.Race, 
                                  LesPontes.EnPonte, LesPontes.Couvant," &
                                 " LesPontes.ŒufsPondus, LesPontes.ŒufsCassés,  
                                LesPontes.Couvés,dbFécondation.Fécondés, dbFécondation.ŒufsClaires" &   
         "FROM dbFécondation inner join LesPontes  ON dbFécondation.CoupleID = LesPontes.CoupleID 
        ORDER BY LesPontes.Pontes;"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(myds, "LesPontes")
        da.Fill(myds, "dbFécondation")
        da.Fill(myds)
        rpt.SetDataSource(myds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    End Using
End Using
End Sub
```

So thank you very much.

Comment: There's a missing space before `FROM`.

Comment: Yes ,That is the error .. Thank you .. I was blind.